# CSS - How to create dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have created a dropdown menu. it works good, but there is a problem I am not able to solve on my own.

```css
.dropdown-toggle ~ .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      }
      .dropdown-toggle:hover ~ .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
      }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Test</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu"> 
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test1</a> 
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test2</a> 
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

If I mouseover the menu - it works if the mouse is over the *dropdown-toggle* class. If I mouseover the element from menu - the whole menu disappear.

I know i can change *dropdown-toggle* to *dropdown* but i want to activate the menu only if mouse is over the .dropdown-toggle, not the whole container.

Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Ref: *"i want to activate the menu only if mouse is over the .dropdown-toggle, not the whole container"*. Isn't this **exactly** what's happening now? Could you make your question clearer? What do you call *"container"*?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to add another property in the css that will make the links displayed- when you hover over them with mouse:

```
.dropdown-toggle ~ .dropdown-menu:hover {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
}
```

Another property that I added is to make sure that you will firstly hover over the main link and then hover over them with mouse, is:

```
.dropdown-toggle ~ .dropdown-menu {
        visibility: hidden;
}
```

When their visibility is hidden, you can't trigger the 'hover' css event on them.

```css
.dropdown-toggle ~ .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      }
      .dropdown-toggle:hover ~ .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-toggle ~ .dropdown-menu:hover {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
      .dropdown-toggle ~ .dropdown-menu {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Test</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu"> 
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test1</a> 
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test2</a> 
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: A simpler method to keep the menu open when hovered is to add `.dropdown-menu:hover` to `.dropdown-toggle:hover ~ .dropdown-menu`, without having to duplicate the declarations. But it looks like that's not the desired behavior, at least if the question is correctly formulated at this point.

Comment: I think that's the intended behavior, too, as what the question seems to ask is already happening. Hopefully OP will clarify.